# Node JS and Express - Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, digital-ocean, nodejs-server

I have this error on my nodejs app (I'm using Nodejs + Express EJS)

```
Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added to [Request]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I do this code `process.setMaxListeners(0);` btw I use Digitalocean

but nothing is happening I still have the problem

this is my app.js code

```
let createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

process.setMaxListeners(0);
app.listen(3000);

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '11mb'}));

let indexRouter = require('./routes/rooms/index');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/home', indexRouter);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's your request?